# Error installing Ubuntu touch on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: live-usb, ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

I am getting an error when trying to install Ubuntu touch on my Galaxy Nexus. I run Ubuntu 13.04 from a live USB, I don't know if the error is related to this.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ phablet-flash -b
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/phablet-flash", line 19, in <module>
    import logging
ImportError: No module named logging
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The package:

```
phablet-tools
```

depends on python which in turn depends on python-minimal

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py
libpython2.7-minimal:amd64: /usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py
```

which provides the logging module.

Comment: Ok, I tried it yesterday and phablet still didn't find the logging module. In addition, it tells me that
_libpython2.7-minimal:amd64: /usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py_

is not a command. I'm pretty sur I'm asking really newbish stuff